# Can't access SSH to Linux VM on Azure

Tags: linux, centos, azure, azure-networking

I am trying to access the Azure Linux VM via SSH with no success to connect.
I'm using centos 7 Linux.
The target IP is reachable by Ping.
It's possible to connect to another vm with the same VNET on azure

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot the connectivity.

Double check for the firewall on Azure portal
Check for NSG Policy
Check for Allowing the SSH Inbound from the internet or specific IP Address
Check for changing the default SSH port if its 22 or another port.
Ping TargetIP
Tracert TargetIP
Lookup URL_TargetIP
Ping PrivateIP
Ping PublicIP

my solution was by entering Serial Console on Azure Portal
check on **netstat -anlp**  for checking SSH service is listening,
allowing rule of the SSH port on firewall
In my case the SSH is non-standard port let's assume its 1234 (in your case may vary)

in the Serial console try the following command to add ssh rule.

**firewall-cmd --reload**
if that does not work then add the custom port of the SSH if that is customized.
**firewall-cmd --add-port=1234/tcp --permanent**
**firewall-cmd –reload**

then try to access the target vm by the SSH client

Comment: I assume you have meant netstat -anlp to check if SSH service is listening. In addition, sshd service should be up and running. Netstat might not be installed by default. Use yum install net-tools to install it.